# Calling procedure from dll in Delphi XE2

Tags: windows, delphi, dll, delphi-xe2, procedure

So, I'm trying to call a procedure from a DLL in Delphi XE2.
but the procedure just won't assign.

I have tried several examples found on the internet.
The DLL is being loaded as expected.
The exports are correctly written.

Everything seems fine but still no success.

What is up with that?

The code I have is the following

```
type
  TStarter = procedure; stdcall;

...

fTheHookStart: TStarter;

...

procedure TForm1.LoadHookDLL;
begin
  LogLn('Keyboard Hook: Loading...');
  // Load the library
  DLLHandle := LoadLibrary('thehookdll.DLL');

  // If succesful ...
  if Handle <> 0 then
  begin
    LogLn('Keyboard Hook: DLL load OK!');
    LogLn('Keyboard Hook: assigning procedure ...');

    fTheHookStart := TStarter(GetProcAddress(DLLHandle, 'StartTheHook'));
    if @fTheHookStart <> nil then
    begin
      LogLn('Keyboard Hook: procedure assignment OK!');
      LogLn('Keyboard Hook: Starting...');
      fTheHookStart;
    end
    else
    begin
      LogLn('Keyboard Hook: procedure assignment FAIL!');
      FreeLibrary(DLLHandle);
      if Handle <> 0 then LogLn('Keyboard Hook: DLL free OK!') else LogLn('Keyboard Hook: DLL free FAIL!');
    end;
  end
  else
  begin
    LogLn('Keyboard Hook: DLL load FAIL!');
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Assuming the code you posted is exactly what you are testing with... You set DLLHandle but then test for `Handle <> 0`...  Maybe it's your DLL itself that fails to load.

Comment: oooohhh now I understand. I didn't even notce that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One error is that you assign **DllHandle** when you load the dll, but then you check if **Handle** <> nil. Handle is actually your forms handle, which ofcourse is not nil. That will not matter if the loading succeeded, but if it failed, you will get wrong logging.
Since you also have some logging functions, what does the log show?

Answer (score 3):

As I understand it, the DLL loads, but `GetProcAddress` returns `nil`. There is only one such failure mode. The DLL does not export a function with that name.

Watch out for name decoration and letter case. C and C++ DLLs may export decorated names. And exported names are sensitive to letter case.

Use `dumpbin` or Dependency Walker to check the exported function name.

For reference, when `GetProcAddress` fails, as the documentation explains, a call to `GetLastError` will yield an error code.

---

And it looks like the other answer is onto something. You believe that you have loaded the DLL correctly, but your code doesn't perform that check correctly.

If you'd called `GetLastError` then the system could have alerted you to this. If you'd inspected the variables under the debugger, the problem would have been obvious.

Comment: But how do I use dumpbin? I've never heard of it before

Comment: It's one of the MS tools. Dependency Walker is easier to use.

Comment: @MartynA A name is a name. If `tdump` gets exported names, that's good. I just happen to use other tools. Depends has a GUI which is comforting for some.

Comment: the export is there. but still not working? is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: If `GetProcAddress` returns `nil` then no function of that name is exported from the DLL you loaded. It is that simple. Either you loaded the wrong DLL or you got the name wrong. Let's be clear, "not working" is imprecise. I stated my assumptions in the answer. Did I get it right? In the question you did not state the output of your program.